# JButton в два столба

Tags: java, swing

Хотелось бы узнать возможно ли сделать кнопку при диспетчере компоновки GridLayout в два столбца (смотрите рис.). И если нет, как можно это реализовать

Буду крайне благодарен за ответ!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам был дан правильный ответ - не забывайте помечать его галкой. Это будет полезно для тех, кто в будущем наткнется на эту тему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При помощи GridLayout этого добиться нельзя, здесь поможет GridBagLayout. Можно указать `gridwidth = 2`, чтобы элемент занимал два столбца по ширине.

```
GridBagConstraints constraints= new GridBagConstraints();
constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
constraints.gridx = 2;
constraints.gridy = 5;
constraints.gridwidth = 2;
add(new JButton("="), constraints);
```

Полный код:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public final class Calculator extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Calculator().setVisible(true);
    }

    public Calculator() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        layout.columnWeights = new double[] {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
        layout.rowWeights = new double[] {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
        setLayout(layout);

        GridBagConstraints constraints;

        constraints = constraints(0, 0);
        constraints.gridwidth = 4;
        JTextField result = new JTextField("0");
        result.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        add(result, constraints);

        add(new JButton("C"), constraints(0, 1));
        add(new JButton("+/-"), constraints(1, 1));
        add(new JButton("<-"), constraints(2, 1));
        add(new JButton("/"), constraints(3, 1));
        add(new JButton("7"), constraints(0, 2));
        add(new JButton("8"), constraints(1, 2));
        add(new JButton("9"), constraints(2, 2));
        add(new JButton("*"), constraints(3, 2));
        add(new JButton("4"), constraints(0, 3));
        add(new JButton("5"), constraints(1, 3));
        add(new JButton("6"), constraints(2, 3));
        add(new JButton("+"), constraints(3, 3));
        add(new JButton("1"), constraints(0, 4));
        add(new JButton("2"), constraints(1, 4));
        add(new JButton("3"), constraints(2, 4));
        add(new JButton("-"), constraints(3, 4));
        add(new JButton("0"), constraints(0, 5));
        add(new JButton("."), constraints(1, 5));

        constraints = constraints(2, 5);
        constraints.gridwidth = 2;
        add(new JButton("="), constraints);
        pack();
    }

    private static GridBagConstraints constraints(int x, int y) {
        final GridBagConstraints result = new GridBagConstraints();
        result.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        result.gridx = x;
        result.gridy = y;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]

Comment: Благодарю за расширенный ответ!